# Dynamic programming stack of plates

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I've been struggling with the following dynamic programming question.
Wondering if anyone knew what was wrong with my solution.

Given an integer n, designating your total plate count, return the total number of plate stackings possible. A valid plate stacking is one where each level has more plates than the one above it for stability. Each level must have at least one plate.

For instance, if n=3, we can stack it one valid way [2,1] so the answer is 1

Similarly, if n=5, we can have [4,1] [3,2] so the answer is 2

A solution attempt in python

```
def main(n):
    m = {}
    m[1] = 1
    m[2] = 1
    m[3] = 1
    m[4] = 1
    return recurse(n, m)

def recurse(n, m):
    if n in m: #Base case
        return m[n]

    sum = 0
    for currP in range(n-1, 0, -1):
        nextP = n-currP #next level plates

        if nextP > currP: #no way to do this level
            break

        sum += recurse(nextP, map) #recursive step

    m[n] = sum
    return m[n]
```

Comment: What output do you get, what would you expect? And what value is n? Is there any other code you missed out?

Comment: The number n is the total amount of plates you have. The expected output is the number of valid plate stackings possible with that many plates. Essentially number of valid sets adding up to n.

Comment: I have what I think is a rather neat solution to this problem in the dupe "Brick Tower Building Puzzle".